# Highlight Google maps V3 Polyline from external function

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I'm wanting to highlight a Polyline when I hover on an anchor tag. Here's my code, the Polyline is being drawn from a gps file which is all working fine but I can't seem to 'setOptions' from an external function

```
<script>

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "myTrack.gpx",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        var points = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
        $(xml).find("trkpt").each(function() {
          var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
          var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
          var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
          points.push(p);
          bounds.extend(p);
        });

        var polyTrack = new google.maps.Polyline({
          // use your own style here
          path: points,                 
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 5
        });

        polyTrack.setMap(map);              

      }
    }); 

    // WHEN I HOVER THE DIV
    function hoverTrack(){

         polyTrack.setOptions({
             strokeOpacity: 1,
             strokeWeight: 10
         });    

     }  


</script>

<a onmouseover="hoverTrack()">HIGHLIGHT</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the var-keyword in

```
var polyTrack =
```

Otherwise the variable will not be global accessible

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring polyTrack as a local variable inside the callback part of the ajax function.

There are several ways to deal with this. A simple one would be to declare the polyline **before** the ajax call, then update its path and display it on the ajax callback. This way, the variable would be available for both the ajax part and the hoverTrack function.

```
    var polyTrack = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 5
        });

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "myTrack.gpx",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        var points = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
        $(xml).find("trkpt").each(function() {
          var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
          var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
          var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
          points.push(p);
          bounds.extend(p);
        });

        polyTrack.setPath(points);
        polyTrack.setMap(map);              

      }
    }); 

    // WHEN I HOVER THE DIV
    function hoverTrack(){
         polyTrack.setOptions({
             strokeOpacity: 1,
             strokeWeight: 10
         });    
     }
```

@Dr.Molle answer should work too. Pay attention to the availability of the map variable. Most google maps examples wrap the map scope inside the initialize function.